# Server unable to browse shares on itself

Tags: windows-server-2008, network-share, service, server-message-block

Having a rather weird issue with our 2008 Domain Controller

When on the server itself and attempting to browse via explorer to \\server or \\192.168.1.1  we get an error message saying : "\\SERVER is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions. The specified network provider name is invalid" the same issue occurs when attempting to browse FROM the server TO a PC on the domain.

However, when going via the start menu, we get the error "\\SERVER The network is not present or not started" and if attempting to browse to \\SERVER\Netlogon we get the error "Windows cannot access \\SERVER\Netlogon Error Code: 0x80070002 (or 0x80004005 when going via explorer to \\SERVER\NETLOGON)

Even though we are having these issues FROM the server, what is also odd is that from any PC on the network you are able to browse to \\SERVER with no issues. To make things even more peculiar when going through cmd, and typing the command "dir \\SERVER\NETLOGON" it will give you a result with the correct files.

Also, while using cmd I have tried the command "net use I: \\Server\Netlogon" and we are getting the error message "The Workstation Service has not been started" but we have confirmed it in fact is.

Finally; for the purposes of testing, we have disabled the firewall, Anti-Virus, and confirmed that services appear to be running correctly. As well as a SFC (just to be sure)

Any insight anyone has on this issue would be much appreciated!
Thanks guys.
P.s apologies if double backslashes are not coming up correctly in the above.

Comment: Is this also a DNS Server? Can it resolve its own name?

Comment: It is also a DNS server, and yes it can resolve it's name. IP addresses are not working either.

Comment: Can it telnet to itself on it's **public address** on port 445?

Comment: Are there more than one DNS servers on your network? What does this server has as primary and secondary DNS set? Is this a virtual machine which was cloned or something? Can you reach the share with its FQDN `\\servername.yourdomain\share`? Are you logged on with a domain account?

Comment: @ Vasili - the ports on the router have not been opened for external use, if this is what you mean. Internally, the server is able to telnet to itself

Comment: @ duenni - there are no other DNS Servers on the neywork, primary is the server itself. And secondary is the ISP dns server, but expecting if DNS issue local IP would work. I believe its related to services that interact with SMB. It is not a physical machine. No cloning or anything. Using FQDN does not work. And yes, have tried multiple domain admin accounts.

Comment: As a first step, remove the ISP DNS server form the DNS client settings on the DC and on all domain clients. A domain client (including the DC) should NEVER use a DNS server other than the AD DNS server. If you want to use the ISP DNS server then set it up as a forwarder in the DNS `server` settings, not the DNS `client` settings. After making this change flush the DNS client cache on all domain clients (including the DC) and try again.

Comment: Thanks Joeqwerty, i have made this change but still has not made any difference, any other ideas?

Comment: Try turning off IPv6 on the server.  We had a very similar issue because IPv6 was not set up on our network but was still enabled on the individual servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the help, but the issue ended up being that there was a Symantec Firewall Driver installed on the NIC. After removing the driver, and turning off and back on file sharing on the LAN connection, it's all working!